# Tweaking FreeRDP for a developper workstation accross seas?

Tags: rdp, freerdp

I need to use FreeRDP to connect **overseas** to a windows desktop located in Canada (I live in Belgium). Now, I also need to connect **through an OpenVPN** connection first before using RDP.

Issue I'm having is that I have a lag when moving around on the remote desktop. As a developper, it makes it quite frustrating to do my work.

Here's a video link demo'ing  this lag:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cpO26YUF2qg

This is the command I use to connect :

````
xfreerdp /u:username /v:192.168.x.x /bpp:8 -grab-keyboard -wallpaper```
````

I tried various bpp settings and it doesn't seem to change much.

Is there a way I could tweak the RDP connection even more ? I need this just to code in IDEs, manage databases, etc. I **do not need** super high-quality graphics or anything (I won't be playing videos from here ;)). I think 256 colors should be fine, but wondering if they are other compression settings I could use?

While I'll have done everything I can with the RDP, my lan admin is also looking into tweaking the VPN connection...

Thanks a million for your time.
Pat

Answer (score 1):

You may try using h264 mode of freerdp (version 2.0 recommended/required). In general, the h264 will use fewer data to transfer the image, but it highly depends on what you are doing, YMMV. It is worth trying, the option is:

```
/gfx-h264[:[[AVC420|AVC444],mask:<value>]
```

/gfx-h264:AVC444 works best for me. There are also several additional gfx-* configuration options, you may test with them.

Comment: As of today, with my version of FreeRDP, I found the faster to be : `/bpp:8 /gfx:avc444 /network:auto -fonts -wallpaper -themes -aero -window-drag -menu-anims` .... You're /gfx-h264 arg no longer exists, but I think my `/gfx:avc444`is the same as what you use.. Thanks for your reply.